# Make the checkbox checked and select option selected after using filter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

Am using filters to display the products accordingly.
I got filtered result correctly. But I cannot retain the filtered results at next filter.
i.e. Am using three filter.
Created at - Date filter
Price - Filter
Seller - Filter

Everything working separately.

But I cannot make it at the next next filtering results. Also, I cannot make the checked value to be checked and selected value to be selected. How can I do it? My code I given below:

Controller:

```
          $category_id = Category::where('name', $main)->value('id');
          if($category_id == "")
          {
            $all_categories_id = Category::pluck('id');
          }
          else
          {
            $all_categories_id = Category::where('parent_id', $category_id)->pluck('id');
            $all_categories_id->push($category_id);
          }
          $product_id = Product::where('name', 'like','%'.$request->name.'%')->pluck('id');
          $id = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $product_id)->whereIn('category_id', $all_categories_id)->pluck('id');
          $product_id = Product::whereIn('id', $id)->pluck('id');
          $seller = Product::whereIn('id', $id)->pluck('seller_id'); 
          $seller_name = User::whereIn('id', $seller)->get(); 

          $products = Product::where(function($query) use ($product_id){
            $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? Input::get('min_price') : null;
            $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? Input::get('max_price') : null;        
            $seller = Input::has('seller') ? Input::get('seller') : [];

            if(isset($min_price) && isset($max_price)){
              $query->whereBetween('price_per_unit', [$min_price, $max_price])
                        ->whereIn('id', $product_id);              
            }

            if(isset($days)){
              foreach($days as $key => $day){
                $end = Carbon::now();
                $get_required_date = Carbon::now()->subDays($day);
                $products = Product::where('created_at', '>', $get_required_date)->pluck('id');
                $query->whereIn('id', $products)->whereBetween('price_per_unit', [$min_price, $max_price]);              
              }
            }

            if(isset($seller)){              
                foreach($seller as $key => $sell){
                  $query->whereIn('id', $product_id)
                        ->where('seller_id', $sell);
               }
            }
            $query->whereIn('id', $product_id);
          })->get();
      }    



        //Categories Name in Sidebar
        $category = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $id)->pluck('parent_id');
        $category_name = Category::whereIn('id', $category)->pluck('name');

        //Categories Name in dropdown
        $main_categories = Category::where('parent_id', '0')->pluck('name'); 

        //Profile Image Mapping
        $user = Auth::user();
        $directory = 'uploads/users/images/'.$user->id;
        $main_categories = Category::where('parent_id', '0')->pluck('name');
        if (is_dir($directory)) {
        $files = scandir ($directory);
        $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
        $user['front_img'] = $img_file;
        }
        $profile = $user['front_img'];

        //Product Image Mapping     
        $products->map(function ($product) {
        $directory = 'uploads/products/images/'.$product->id;
        $brand = Brand::select('name')->where('id', '=', $product->brand)->pluck('name');
        $brand_name = $brand->first(function($value, $key) {
          return $key == 'name';
        });
        if (is_dir($directory)) {
          $files = scandir ($directory);
          $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
          $product['front_img'] = $img_file;
          $product['brand'] = $brand_name;
          return $product;
        }
          return $product;
        });

      return view('pages/product', compact('main_categories','seller_name', 'profile', 'products', 'main', 'category_name'));
```

And my Blade code:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<section class="bc-product">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="breadcrumb-width">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <ul class="bc-breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active category"><a href="#">{{$main}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <ul class="bc-Produc-mlist">
              <li>View:Sort :</li>
              <li><a href="#"> Popular</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> NewDiscount </a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Price: LowHigh</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="bc-Product-left hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="bc-categories-left">
          <span class="bc-expand-title">CATEGORIES</span>
          <a class="bc-expand">
          <div class="bc-expand-icon">[ - ]</div>
          </a>
          <div class="bc-detail-list">
            <ul class="bc-categories-list">
              @foreach($category_name as $m)
              <li><a href="{{url('/product/'.$m)}}"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$m}}</a></li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <form id="filterform">
        <div class="bc-categories-left">
        <div class="bc-product-mtb">
          <span class="bc-expand-title">New Arrival</span>
          <a class="bc-expand">
          <div class="bc-expand-icon">[ - ]</div>
          </a>
          <div class="bc-detail-list">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-select"> 
              <input id="7" name="days[]" value="7" type="checkbox"/>
              <label for="7"> Last 07 days </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-select">
              <input value="15" name="days[]" id="15" type="checkbox"/>               
              <label for="15">Last 15 days </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-select">
              <input id="30" name="days[]" value="30" type="checkbox"/>
              <label for="30">Last 30 days </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-select">
              <input id="45" name="days[]" value="45" type="checkbox"/>
              <label for="45"> Last 45 days </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bc-categories-left">
         <div class="bc-product-mtb">
          <span class="bc-expand-title">Price</span>
          <a class="bc-expand">
          <div class="bc-expand-icon">[ - ]</div>
          </a>
          <div class="bc-detail-list">
            <div class="bc-range-bar">
              <div class="bc-range-handle-left"></div>
              <div class="bc-range-handle-right"></div>
            </div>
            <!--<input id="range" type="range" min="20" max="200"/>-->
            <div class="form-group bc-form-pric-sm">
              <select name="min_price" class="bc-select">
                <option value="0">Min</option>
                <option value="200" >$200</option>
                <option value="500" >$500</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group bc-input-group">
              <select name="max_price" class="bc-select">
                <option value="1000000000000000">Max</option>
                <option value="2000" >$2000</option>
                <option value="5000" >$5000</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bc-categories-left">
         <div class="bc-product-mtb">
         <?php $seller = Input::has('seller') ? Input::get('seller') : []; ?>
          <span class="bc-expand-title">Seller</span>
          <a class="bc-expand">
          <div class="bc-expand-icon">[ - ]</div>
          </a>
          <div class="bc-detail-list">
          <?php $seller = Input::has('seller') ? Input::get('seller') : []; ?>
          @foreach($seller_name as $seller)
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-select">
              <input id="{{$seller->id}}" name="seller[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$seller->id}}">
              <label for="{{$seller->id}}"> {{$seller->name}} </label>
            </div>
          @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="active" style="display: none;">ok</button>
      <div class="bc-Product-right">
          @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="bc-product-col">
          <div class="bc-product-list">
          <div class="bc-product-listimg">
            <img src="{{ asset($product->front_img) }}" alt="Women">
          </div>
          <div class="bc-actions">
            <a class=" bc-buy-line bc-view" href="#">View</a>
            <a class="bc-buy" href="/buy-now">Buy</a>
          </div>
          <span class="bc-brand-name">{{$product->name}}</span>
          <span class="bc-price">{{$product->price_per_unit}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
          @endforeach
      </form>
        <div class="text-right">
          <div class="page-nation">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-large">
              <li class="disabled"><span>Prev</span></li>
              <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">4</a>
              </li>
              <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
              <li>
              <li><a rel="next" href="#">Next</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
$("input[name='seller[]']").click(function() {
  $( "button.active" ).trigger( "click" );
});
$("input[name='days[]']").click(function() {
  $( "button.active" ).trigger( "click" );
});
$("select[name='max_price'").change(function() {
  $( "button.active" ).trigger( "click" );
});
// $("#range").change(function(){
//   var val = $('#range').val();
//   console.log(val);
// });
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such scenario, you can use `ajax()` instead of form submit. But if you don't want to use `ajax()` and continue with the form submit approach then you have to maintain the state on your own. To do this you have to return from controller which elements are checked or what value is selected in dropdown and make it checked and selected on behalf of these values. laravel provide this approach `return redirect with input`

You can use it like:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());
```

Comment: How to do that? Even if I did, will I able to retain it for the next filter?

Comment: With which approach you want to go with? `ajax()` or `form submit`? I suggest you to use `ajax()`

Comment: Form submit only. Because in ajax, I feel it difficult

Comment: Check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/keep-the-state-checked-on-the-next-filter-requests

Comment: I have one idea. I don't know whether it will work out or not. First time when I apply filter, it works by passing the parameter to the url. Next time I apply filter, can i get the parameter from the url and apply two filter if parameter present?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144412/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-kayal).